# Multiple ViewControllers upon tapping with swipe left action

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Right now, I'm trying to connect different ViewControllers with various actions ( edit, add, download, delete ) upon swiping to the left and tapping thereafter.

I can do it with accessory actions, if it is just 1 action ( which for now I've hooked up to edit ). I've attempted to hooked up to AddViewController but somehow it won't work anymore with accessory action. I understand that there can only be 1 accessory action, so how should I even begin to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see what you've done and where the problem might be?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom I've uploaded to dropbox, https://www.dropbox.com/s/34nqi6w2hilflt5/TestApp3.zip?dl=0 as I fear I can't explain clearly

Comment: So basically, you want those buttons to work instead of just edit?

Comment: I need to understand how to make multiple buttons to call their respective xxxViewController, if that is what you mean. I can make it work if it is just 1 Edit , 1 Delete, but if I wanted to display multiple ViewControllers respectively, this is where I'm at a lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure if I understood you correctly. You should be able doing that just by using the `handler` block of `UITableViewRowAction` the way you have been doing for the button `edit`. I've used your code to create several examples, I hope this is what you meant:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject] {
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Share") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

            if self.programmatically {
                // Segue to "shareFriendsSegue through a segue
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shareFriendsSegue", sender:self)
            } else {
                // Programmatically without identifier
                let destination1 = SomeViewController()
                destination1.dataYouWantToPass = self.someData
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination1, animated: true)

                // Programmatically with an identifier
                let destination2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! SomeViewController
                destination2.dataYouWantToPass = self.someData
                self.showDetailViewController(destination2, sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
            let testObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSObject

            // Segue to "editSegue" through a segue
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editSegue", sender:self)
        }
    }

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        // Delete the row from tableView
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)

        // Delete the row from Core Data
        if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            context.deleteObject(object)
        }

        var error: NSError?
        if(self.managedObjectContext!.save(&error)) {
            if error != nil {
                println(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    var fourth = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "fourth") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

            if self.programmatically {
                // Segue to "shareFriendsSegue through a segue
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("anotherSegue", sender:self)
            } else {
                // Programmatically without identifier
                let destination1 = AnotherViewController()
                destination1.dataYouWantToPass = self.someData
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination1, animated: true)

                // Programmatically with an identifier
                let destination2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("anotherViewController") as! AnotherViewController
                destination2.dataYouWantToPass = self.someData
                self.showDetailViewController(destination2, sender: self)
            }
        }

    }

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 107.0/255.0, blue: 107.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 85.0/255.0, green: 98.0/255.0, blue: 112.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return [deleteAction, editAction, shareAction, fourth]
}
```

In these examples 3 different ways are used to change the view:

1. Through a segue. You can pass whatever data you want in the method `prepareForSegue`.
2. Instantiating through the storyboard. You'll need to set an identifier, similar to how you set a segue name.
3. Create a new instance of a ViewController using an initializer.

Let me know if this is what you were searching for.

Comment: Ah, looks like instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is the one I'm looking for, thanks mate...